# Access props/attributes from child component with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a feature to easily hide/show all items (subcomponents). By using `useState` I am able to set whether or not all items are hidden/shown. By using `useEffect` I am able to toggle items that are hidden/shown. I'm having issues accessing the props in the subcomponent to determine whether or not a an item has already been expanded. I wish I could explain this better, but hopefully this coding example will paint a better picture.

**index.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";
import { Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import Item from "./Item";

const Services = props => {
  const [allExpanded, setAllExpanded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <p>
        <Button onClick={() => setAllExpanded(false)} content="Hide all" />
        <Button onClick={() => setAllExpanded(true)} content="Show all" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <Item expanded={allExpanded} />
        <Item expanded={allExpanded} />
        <Item expanded={allExpanded} />
      </p>
    </>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Services />, rootElement);
```

**Item.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Accordion } from "semantic-ui-react";

const Item = props => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(props.expanded);

  useEffect(() => {
    setExpanded(props.expanded);
  }, [props.expanded]);

  return (
    <Accordion styled>
      <Accordion.Title
        onClick={() => {
          setExpanded(!expanded);
        }}
      >
        <p>{expanded ? "- Hide Item" : "+ Show Item"}</p>
      </Accordion.Title>
      <Accordion.Content active={expanded}>Lorem ipsum...</Accordion.Content>
    </Accordion>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-sunset-w09mp?fontsize=14)

To replicate my current bug, click any "+ Show Item", then click "Hide All". It will not hide everything, however clicking "Show All", then "Hide All" will hide everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're facing this issue because your parent component actually has three possible states:

- All expanded
- All collapsed
- Neither all expanded or collapsed

To reflect the third state, you could use null/undefined (and pass the setter down into your children components).

Updated example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-villani-i6ggh

Answer (score 0):

Since you are handling the expanded state of your accordions on the top level, I suggest you just pass down the expanded state and the 'toggler' to your items. `index.js` will handle the logic and your `Item` component will be presentational.

Here's a fork of your [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/brave-galileo-p4v0r).

It doesn't look great and probably the item state and toggling can (and probably should) be moved elsewhere (for example a separate reducer with the usage of the `useReducer` [hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer))

If you are planning to create these components dynamically, IMO this is the easiest way to go.

If you still want to go your way, you can refactor your `Item` to a class component and use [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to get their current state, however I *not recommend* this approach.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a codeandsandbox, forked from yours:

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-wildflower-n0hb8

I changed it so that instead of having something like this:

```
let [allExpanded, setAllExpanded] = useState(true)
```

You have something like this:

```
let [whichExpanded, setWhichExpanded] = useState({0: true, 1:true, 2: true})
```

Then, on for your callback to expand/collapse all buttons, you have this:

```
<button onClick=()=>{
    let newState = {}
    for(let order in whichEpanded){
       newState[order] = false //change every key to false
    }
    setAllExpanded(newState)
}> hide all</button>
```

Then, I passed down an "order" prop to your items.  The "order" prop is used as an argument to a callback function that I pass down, so when you click on each item, it updates the whichExpanded state, to toggle the visibility of just that one item.

```
 // pass this to eac of the items:
 const setIndividualItemExpanded = order => {
    let newItemsExpandedState = { ...itemsExpanded };
    newItemsExpandedState[order] = !newItemsExpandedState[order];
    setItemsExpanded(newItemsExpandedState);
  };
```

Each item component:

```
  <Item
      expanded={itemsExpanded[0]} //is reading from the state
      order={0}
      setExpanded={setIndividualItemExpanded}
    />
```

Then, you can remove the useState from the rendered component and just update with the "setExpanded" prop

(See complete code in codesandbox pasted at top)